# Javascript formatting for OnClick function

Tags: javascript, formatting

**EDIT: Here is the entire chunck of what is in the table**

Hopefully this will help, now the code that worked before for the alert is no longer working. Does this have to do with it being in a table?

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/fT8aL/13/

---

I've got a webapp that I'm trying to modify a little. Anyways when I click on a link I want it to call a function which sends an email. The first item is text on the page and the second is a variable which calls the username.

In a .jsp file I'm modifying the following line:

```
<a href="${videoUrl}" target="main" onclick="sendMail(this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('span')[2].attributes['title'].value, '${model.user.username}')">
```

The above code works when testing it with an alert instead of the sendMail function. You can view it here: http://jsfiddle.net/rr6Wk/72/

My problem is its not sending the email, I'm guessing I've got some incorrect formatting or something on the above code.

Any ideas?

Function:

```
<script>
function sendMail(video, user) {
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
     } else {// IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
     }
xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://www.yourdomain.com/somedirectory/sendemail.php?video="+video+"&user="+user+'&ip=<%= request.getHeader("X-Real-IP") %>', false);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

This works but is not usable because all items have the nicename ID:

```
<a href="${videoUrl}" target="main" onclick="sendMail(document.getElementById('nicename').title, '${model.user.username}')">
```

In another file called main.jsp is where the name comes from, I added the id="nicename" however this doesn't work because if I click on the 3rd item it always shows the nicename from the first item:

```
<td ${class} style="padding-right:1.25em;white-space:nowrap">
<span id="nicename" title="${child.title}"><str:truncateNicely upper="${cutoff}">${fn:escapeXml(child.title)}</str:truncateNicely></span>
</td>
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging with the browser's developer tools to see what, if anything, is being sent and/or returned?

Comment: Have you checked the server logs? Is sendemail.php flagging any errors? This sounds more like a backend problem than a frontend problem... unless the XHR request is incorrect.

Comment: I know the sendmail.php works, If I use this code it sends an email. But it doesnt work properly because all things listed on the page have the same id

<a href="${videoUrl}" target="main" onclick="sendMail(document.getElementById('nicename').title, '${model.user.username}')">

Comment: @nutt318: Could you edit your question to include the HTML that contains the tags with the same `nicename` ID? And which one do you want to use?

Comment: @Jay: I added the part of code where the name comes from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getElementById` will always return the first element if there are multiple elements with the same ID. Thus, it won't be applicable for that purpose. Either use a different ID for each *nicename*, or use `name` (instead of ID) attribute with `getElementsByName`.

For `getElementsByName` example:

```
<script>
    function doSendMail(videoIndex, userName) {
        //get the list of nicename elements
        var eles = document.getElementsByName('nicename');
        //send the mail. note: error handling is absent
        sendMail(eles[videoIndex].title, userName);
    }
</script>
<!--send mail for the 3rd video-->
<a href="${videoUrl}" target="main" onclick="doSendMail(2, '${model.user.username}')">
```

A third option is to use a relative element reference based on the clicked element using `this` and *walking* the HTML nodes to get the required element (the title). In the provided jsfiddle, the table has 7 columns. The element to be clicked is in column 2 (play link) and the required element is in column 6 (`SPAN` element). Neither `name` nor `id` attribute is necessary for this method.

```
<script>
function doSendMail(playLinkEle, user) {
  var row = playLinkEle.parentNode.parentNode; //get cell, then row
  var cell = row.cells[5]; //get 6th cell (same row)
  var ele = cell.firstElementChild; //get first child element
  sendMail(ele.title, user);
}
</script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      star image
    </td>
    <td>
      <a onclick="doSendMail(this, '${model.user.username}')" target="main" href="${videoUrl}">play link</a>
    </td>
    <td>
      empty column
    </td>
    <td>
      download link
    </td>
    <td>
      song id
    </td>
    <td>
      unknown detail
    </td>
    <td>
      <span title="The Title">The Title</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      duration detail
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>


      duration detail
```

Comment: so when I click on the link how does it know which video it is? I see you get a list of all names but how would it get 2 for it?

Is there a way to add a loop or a increase of say: nicename1, nicename2, nicename3 and then have it get the proper name?

Comment: Added a third option based on your table. Might be easier to adopt.

Comment: I tried your 3rd option and I'm getting this error 
`Uncaught ReferenceError: playLinkElement is not defined main.view:3110
doSendMail main.view:3110
onclick
`

Comment: Sorry. `playLinkElement` should have been `playLinkEle`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<a href="${videoUrl}" target="main" onclick="sendMail(this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('span')[2].attributes['title'].value, '${model.user.username}');">
```

You need to make sure there are at least 3 spans selected by `getElementsByTagName`

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. 

However this does but it grabs the very first element that has 'nicename' for an ID.

<a href="${videoUrl}" target="main" onclick="sendMail(document.getElementById('nicename').title, '${model.user.username}')">

Comment: Not sure how to properly add a debug statement but your suggestions gave me this error in chromes console 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL '

without the added '"+ it gave this error 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'attributes' of undefined -
onclick

Comment: it shows that you don't have up to 3 spans and you were trying to access the third span. `0-first, 1-second, 2-third`

Comment: My answer introduced the `ILLEGAL` error and I have corrected it. Take care of the spans, the code is not seeing up to 3 which `[2]` referred to. And that's probably why you get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'attributes' of undefined`

Comment: Well I've tried 0-5 and nothing works, I beleive it should be [2] because its the 3rd span after the onclick. If you look here: http://jsfiddle.net/rr6Wk/72/ its the source from the live page, its showing it as the 3rd span, unless I'm missing something

Comment: Just thought of something but not sure how javascript exactly works but the onclick function is in one .jsp file while the name i want is in another .jsp. 

Could that cause the issue with it not finding the 3rd span even though when looking at the live source from the page it looks correct?

Comment: What matters is you checking the generated html source in the browser and see the relationship between the tags (DOM hierarchy). As long as the html is correctly formed, your script should work - look in the source

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help everything, finally got it working by using 2 parentElements!

```
<a href="${videoUrl}" target="main" onclick="sendMail(parentElement.parentElement.getElementsByTagName('span')[2].attributes['title'].value, '${model.user.username}');">
```